# Graph paper replacement software : preferred Linux

Tags: graphics, coordinates

I need to do something in openGL which forces me to take a pencil and a paper to do graphwork. I would like to know if there is free program to do that. It have Axes (X-Y-Z) and I can plot let say a cube and get coordinates.
Sorry but complex program for modelling like blender are not option here. I need something to replace simple coordinate geometry I could do on paper. No fancy color, material or anything of that sort. 
Thanks

Comment: I found GeoGebra, looks promising.
Iam trying it out!

Comment: It works fine, this can be closed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) is a perfect solution!

Comment: Great. Now I could avoid pen and paper to draw graphs by hand.